# Typescript: Returning an object that returns promise type definition

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am fairly new to TS and have been stuck on this particular issue.

I am building an object with reduce which wraps the object methods in a function. I need the object to return the keys of the original object and also the promise of the apiDispatch function and this as far as I have got.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
const actions = {
  getSomething: ({ id }) => ({
    url: `/something/${id}`
  })
};

function buildClient() {
  const apiDispatch = async (data: any) => Promise;

  return Object.entries(actions).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    acc[key] = (data: any, options: any): Promise<any> =>
      apiDispatch({
        ...value(data),
        ...options
      });
    return acc;
  }, {} as typeof actions);
}

const client = buildClient();

client.getSomething({ id: 123 }).then((res: any) => res);
```

1. `acc[key]` giving the following error - `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type`
2. `client.getSomething().then()` the then is not assigned to the type

Link to codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-2yg63?file=/index.ts

Comment: You can assign the type of actions using `actions: Record<string, any>` like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-vyn1r?file=/index.ts

Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood, `getSomething` property should expect two parameters at the end.

```js
const acts = {
  getSomething: ({ id }: { id: string }) => ({
    url: `/something/${id}`
  }),
  getSomethingElse: ({ name }: { name: string }) => ({
    url: `/something/${name}`
  })
} as const;

type Actions = typeof acts;

type Fn = (...args: any[]) => object

const apiDispatch = <T,>(data: T) => Promise.resolve(data);

type Convert<T extends Record<string, Fn>> = {
  [Prop in keyof T]: <Options extends object>(data: Parameters<T[Prop]>[0], options: Options) => Promise<any>
}

type O = Convert<typeof acts>

const buildClient = <
  Keys extends string,
  Value extends Fn,
  Rec extends Record<Keys, Value>
>(actions: Rec) =>
  Object.entries<Value>(actions).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => ({
    ...acc,
    [key]: <T, U>(data: T, options: U) => apiDispatch({
      ...value(data),
      ...options
    })

  }), {} as Convert<Rec>);

const client = buildClient(acts)

const result = client.getSomething({ id: 'dsf' }, {}).then(data => data) // ok
const result2 = client.getSomethingElse({ name: 'dsf' }, {}).then(data => data) // ok
const result3 = client.getSomethingElse({ id: 'dsf' }, {}).then(data => data) // expected error
```

Just friendle advise, try to avoid mutations in TS.
[Here](https://catchts.com/mutations), in my blog, you can find some issues you may encounter mutating the values in TS

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve your problem by changing just one line. In this case TypeScript isn't smart enough to understand that the assignment in this place is allowed. So what I had to do is to change the types a bit (like Sean) but then change it back using the `as` operator in TypeScript.

This is how the code looks now:

```
type OverrideReturn<T extends (...args: any[]) => any, R> = (...args: Parameters<T>) => R;

const actions = {
  getSomething: ({ id }: { id: any }) => ({
    url: `/something/${id}`
  })
};

function buildClient() {
  const apiDispatch = async (data: any) => ({ name: "test object" });

  return Object.entries(actions).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    acc[key] = (data: any, options: any): Promise<any> =>
      apiDispatch({
        ...value(data),
        ...options
      });
    return acc;
  }, {} as Record<string, any>) as {} as { [K in keyof typeof actions]: OverrideReturn<typeof actions[K], Promise<any>> };

}

const client = buildClient();

client.getSomething({ id: 123 }).then((res: any) => res);
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gbhAToglgEwgJQsArogOwB4AVKCAD2AgLQGcoAKAOlYENEBzOgLijYIgA2gF0AlFAC8APn6CANFEyzJTVsw7c+ABQ5sAtjiR1S0iTKUBuAFDWAxgHsCdYPzvAUThqoDe1qFCcOADKDobAABYoBJx8jD5Q6FAAvnwJ6HwCICnmsvH+AVD4ADZ8AAYA9HRhOFExFQAkPujJZQXJYtbJNtYAZrgE7p4EUABGuCjFaADCxSg0wIwSfgGOzq5sYCgAIih0YGzAdhFS-HQgg0xoh2yZgrlMCQQGEHwARNQuUA6jAFYQ7jeOR6AUQOHwIxgfwBwGYC1QEDojDYQy8YmYYLQuDsEEYyLsdkUQgA1hAQIo4GxirgIOIpLIVoUUXYSWSRKdGNdgLc5OTvmAPF47iAxDpEGE9hAiFkVNICoV+FtdvtDsd8gqFepKdTcVy2GJ5PKNeoHALhnQjQEOjYFWC8IQ3HYbSlFD5kmclACHIg0EQXKgYooZRI2Aw3R6EkIANKJEakkAOXpQUCQRNuQXOER8eBIVAYbD24gpiBplEZujRkSKbTi-SS6WCaSybq2ZK2NZfOxzBancaTGbdgiLMQ9LvzIfMILAULhOqceKJNB8ACMACYAMw5ZiRGh4sG8XkPfcj6xAA)

Answer (score -1):

### UPDATE

The reason why you are getting this error is that you defined `{} as typeof actions`. With this, Typescript is expecting your `acc` to be the same as your `actions`. But since you want your `acc` to be something different, therefore you will need to define a new return type for it.

1. Define the new type for `buildClient`, here you can make use of **Typescript Generic Type** if the `actions` type can be changed from time to time. With the new type definition below, the `Client` type will be an object that has the same property keys as the generic type and the value for each key will be a function that returns Promise.

> `type Client<T> = Record<keyof T, (data: any, options?: any) => Promise<any>>;`

2. Define `buildClient` to be a generic function that receives a generic type `T`

> `function buildClient<T>()`

3. Put `acc[key as keyof T]`, to let Typescript knows that property keys will be coming from generic type `T`.
4. Put `{} as Client<T>`, to let Typescript knows that `{}` is `Client<T>` type instead of an empty object.
5. When you call `buildClient`, just put in `<typeof actions>` alongside it, so that Typescript will replace all the generic type `T` with `typeof actions`

> `const client = buildClient<typeof action>()`

After all these changes, Typescript will now understand that `client` only has one property `getSomething` and it's a function that returns a promise. So, the final code will be:

```
type Client<T> = Record<keyof T, (data: any, options?: any) => Promise<any>>;

const actions = {
  getSomething: ({ id }) => ({
    url: `/something/${id}`
  })
};

function buildClient<T>(): Client<T> {
  const apiDispatch = async (data: any) => Promise;

  return Object.entries(actions).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    acc[key as keyof T] = (data: any, options: any): Promise<any> =>
      apiDispatch({
        ...value(data),
        ...options
      });
    return acc;
  }, {} as Client<T>);
}

const client = buildClient<typeof actions>();

client.getSomething({ id: 123 }).then((res: any) => res);
```

Comment: You won't get type safety anymore with the returned object.

Comment: @Sean thanks for your reply. This does suppress the type error but I want to be able to type client. and have intellisense suggest the functions in the actions object e.g. `client.getSomething({ id: 123 })` the problem with using `as typeof actions` is that TS doesn't know that the `client.getSomething()` function  should return a Promise

Comment: @James Sorry my bad, I have misunderstood your question. I have updated my answer based on your feedback.